# Using a constructor function to hold parameters fixed: how does it works?

Tags: r, optimization, subset

**The problem**

I am trying to understand how a constructor function manages to hold parameters fixed when we want it to.

I am looking at the example in Peng's online [book](https://rdpeng.github.io/Biostat776/lecture-scoping-rules-of-r.html#application-optimization), which I post below.

In this case, the constructor function `make.NegLogLik` is used to build a function, `nLL` that calculates the negative log-likelihood (later on in the book,`nLL`  will be optimized.)

**The function**

This is the constructor function in action.

The constructor function itself:

```r
make.NegLogLik <- function(data, fixed = c(FALSE, FALSE)) {
  params <- fixed
  function(p) {
    params[!fixed] <- p
    mu <- params[1]
    sigma <- params[2]
    
    ## Calculate the Normal density
    a <- -0.5*length(data)*log(2*pi*sigma^2)
    b <- -0.5*sum((data-mu)^2) / (sigma^2)
    -(a + b)
  } 
}
```

Now let's use it to *create* another function, `nLL`, that actually calculates the negative log-likelihood

```r
set.seed(1)
normals <- rnorm(100, 1, 2)

nLL <- make.NegLogLik(normals, c(FALSE, FALSE))
```

Meaning that no parameter is fixed. If I call `nLL` now, it returns a function:

```r
nLL
#> function(p) {
#>     params[!fixed] <- p
#>     mu <- params[1]
#>     sigma <- params[2]
#>     
#>     ## Calculate the Normal density
#>     a <- -0.5*length(data)*log(2*pi*sigma^2)
#>     b <- -0.5*sum((data-mu)^2) / (sigma^2)
#>     -(a + b)
#>   }
```

Now I use it:

```r
nLL(c(1,2))
#> [1] 201.7361
```

But I can also use `make.NegLogLik` to build. a different `nLL` in which one parameter is fixed:

```r
nLL <- make.NegLogLik(normals, c(FALSE, 2))
nLL(1)
#> [1] 201.7361
```

**Question**

How does actually `make.NegLogLik` make it work?

It sets `fixed = c(FALSE, FALSE)` first. Then: `params <- fixed`, meaning that `params` is of course equal to `c(FALSE, FALSE)`.

What I don't understand is inside `function(p)`, in particular, this line:

```r
params[!fixed] <- p
```

I know that `!fixed` is equal to `c(TRUE, TRUE)`, but isn't it going to be overwritten by `p` anyway?

If I try it step by step:

```r
fixed = c(FALSE, 2)
params <- fixed
!fixed
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
p <- 1
params[!fixed] <- p
params[!fixed]
#> [1] 1
mu <- params[1]
sigma <- params[2]
mu
#> [1] 1
sigma
#> [1] 2
```

I see that it is working, but again I don't understand how `params[!fixed] <- p` is making it work.

What tricks me is that `p` in this case is just one number, `1`, because I set `sigma = 2`; but `p` could be `c(1,2)`, and still `params[!fixed] <- p` would work.

<sup>Created on 2021-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it, what `params[!fixed] <- p` does is to assign the value of `p` to whatever slot in `params` corresponds to `!fixed` equal to TRUE.

```r
# Example 1, with `fixed = c(FALSE, 2)`
fixed = c(FALSE, 2)
fixed
#> [1] 0 2
params <- fixed
params
#> [1] 0 2
!fixed
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
p <- 1
params[!fixed] <- p
params[!fixed]
#> [1] 1
params
#> [1] 1 2

# Example 2, with `fixed = c(FALSE, FALSE)`
fixed = c(FALSE, FALSE)
fixed
#> [1] FALSE FALSE
params <- fixed
params
#> [1] FALSE FALSE
!fixed
#> [1] TRUE TRUE
p <- c(1,2)
params[!fixed] <- p
params[!fixed]
#> [1] 1 2
params
#> [1] 1 2

# Example 3, with `fixed = c(1, FALSE)`
fixed = c(1, FALSE)
fixed
#> [1] 1 0
params <- fixed
params
#> [1] 1 0
!fixed
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
p <- 2
params[!fixed] <- p
params[!fixed]
#> [1] 2
params
#> [1] 1 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>